# Don't switch to math-mode when entering `$` in a `minted` environment

Tags: latex, auctex, syntax-highlighting

I am using AUCTeX to edit Latex files and use the `minted` package to highlight source-code within documents. Unfortunately the character `$` is still recognized as a delimiter for a math-mode even though it is located within a minted-block and should have no special meaning whatsoever.

[image]

This totally breaks syntax-highlighting and makes emacs think I am editing in math-mode although I am not.

Is it possible to configure AUCTex in such a way as to give characters within a minted environment no special meaning? Or do I have to apply some sort of quoting to `$`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add minted environments to the latex-verbatim-environment variable:

`M-x customize-variable latex-verbatim-environments`, insert a new string "minted", and save your changes. You may need to reload your .tex file for the changes to take effect.

After doing this, `minted` environments will not be fontified at all, so it won't matter if you include `$` symbols.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this happens automatically if file parsing is enabled. It may be worth mentioning it

Comment: @giordano I have enabled both TeX-parse-self and TeX-auto-save, and still needed to manually add minted to `latex-verbatim-environments`.

Comment: Which version of AUCTeX are you using?

Comment: @giordano 11.90.0

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look in the next days.

Comment: @Tyler - If you open your .tex file with `\usepackage{minted}` and look into `*Messages*` buffer, do you see that Emacs load `path/to/minted.elc`?  What happens if you hit `C-c C-n` in your .tex file?

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to give an answer which is complementary to the one given by @Tyler.

I'd recommend that you set this in your init file:

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

restart your Emacs and open your .tex file again.  The difference is that AUCTeX provides a support file `minted.el` for `minted` package which does a lot more besides fixing the fontification in environments and macros provided by `minted` package.  You can hit <kbd>C-c C-e minted RET</kbd> and will be asked for optional argument and the language for your code; both with auto-completion.  Your .tex file could look like this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{bash}
$ echo "Hello"
$ echo World
\end{minted}

\begin{Minted}
  $ echo "Hello"
  $ echo World
\end{Minted}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
%%% End:
```

Note that `Minted` is just an arbitrary environment to show the difference that code will be indented with 2 spaces where spaces are significant.  Here a screenshot for the fontification:

> [image]

The line

```
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
```

allows you to use <kbd>C-c C-a</kbd> in Emacs and your file gets compiled correctly with `minted`.

Answer (score 0):

I still had this problem with a recent distribution of AUCTex, so I looked for an answer. The one given here did not solved my problem. Yet, I added the following command to my `.emacs` file and everything went fine:

```
(setq LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local '("minted"))
```

I hope this might help some people.

Answer (score 0):

As a further alternative, you can give give your blocks their natural highlighting and major-mode using [mmm-mode](https://github.com/dgutov/mmm-mode).

For example, if you evaluate the following elisp code, load up a tex file and do `M-x mmm-mode`, then \begin{minted}{bash} blocks behave as if they were in `bash-ts-mode`:

```el
(require 'mmm-auto)
(require 'mmm-region)

(defvar tex-bash-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap)
  "Keymap for `tex-bash-mode'.")

(define-minor-mode tex-bash-mode
  "Minor mode for minted blocks with bash submode.
This is not intended to be activated manually."
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " MB"
  :keymap tex-bash-mode-map)

(defun tex-bash-initialize ()
  "Initialize `tex-bash-mode'.
Define the `latex-minted-bash' class and add it to `LaTeX-mode'."
  (mmm-add-classes
   '((latex-minted-bash
      :submode bash-ts-mode
      :face mmm-default-submode-face
      :front "\\\\begin{minted}{bash}"
      :back "\\\\end{minted}"
      :save-matches 1
      :insert ((?b bashcode nil @ "\\begin{minted}{bash}" @ "\n" _ "\n" @ "\\end{minted}" @)))))
  ;; (mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'latex-mode "\\.tex\\'" 'latex-minted-bash)
  (mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'latex-mode nil 'latex-minted-bash)
  ;; AUCTeX 13.3+:
  (mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'LaTeX-mode nil 'latex-minted-bash))

(defun tex-bash-enable ()
  "Enable `tex-bash-mode' in the current buffer."
  (setq-local indent-line-function #'tex-bash--indent-line-narrowed)
  (tex-bash-mode 1))

(defun tex-bash-disable ()
  "Disable `tex-bash-mode' in the current buffer."
  (tex-bash-mode 0))

(defun tex-bash--indent-line-narrowed ()
  "An indent function which works on some modes where `mmm-indent-line' doesn't.
Works like `mmm-indent-line', but narrows the buffer before
indenting to appease modes which rely on constructs
like (point-min) to indent."
  (interactive)
  (let ((indent-function
         (save-excursion
           (back-to-indentation)
           (mmm-update-submode-region)
           (get
            (if (and mmm-current-overlay
                     (> (overlay-end mmm-current-overlay)
                        (point)))
                mmm-current-submode
              mmm-primary-mode)
            'mmm-indent-line-function))))
    (if mmm-current-overlay
        (save-restriction
          (narrow-to-region (overlay-start mmm-current-overlay)
                            (overlay-end mmm-current-overlay))
          (funcall indent-function))
      (funcall indent-function))))

(tex-bash-initialize)

(add-hook 'mmm-bash-mode-enter #'tex-bash-enable)
(add-hook 'mmm-bash-mode-exit #'tex-bash-disable)
```

Here's what it looks like:[image]

(The alignment is wrong, but hitting tab would correct it.)

You can do this for each programming language that you use.  The above code is adapted from my package [czm-tex-mint](https://github.com/ultronozm/czm-tex-mint.el), which does something similar for minted `sage` blocks.