# How can I avoid switching into font-latex-math-face in tikzpicture environment?

Tags: auctex, font-lock, math

When I have text inside `\begin{equation}  ... \end{equation}`, `font-latex-math-face` face is applied.

If I have a`tikzpicture` block inside `equation`, `font-latex-math-face` face is applied to it as well:

```tex
\begin{equation} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        ... % font-latex-math-face is applied, which I don't want 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
```

Is it possible to prevent `font-latex-math-face` from being applied to the `tikzpicture` block even though it's inside the equation block?

Related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30427/18414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Sample `demo.tex` file that has `tikzpicture` within a `equation`***

```tex
% Created 2022-10-14 Fri 14:48
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\hypersetup{
 pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 29.0.50 (Org mode 9.5.5)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center)]
\node {sqrt} % root
  child { node {sqrt-iter}
                  child[sibling distance=5cm] { node{ good-enough }
                          child[sibling distance=2cm] { node { square } }
                          child[sibling distance=2cm] { node { abs } } }
                  child { node{ improve }
                          child { node { average } } } };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}  

\begin{equation} 
  x=\sqrt{b}
\end{equation}   

If \(a^2=b\) and \(b=2\), then the solution must be
either $$ a=+\sqrt{2} $$ or \[ a=-\sqrt{2} \].

\end{document}
```

***How the above `tex` file is rendered***

[image: PDF view of above tex file]

***How the buffer looks like in `emacs -Q`***

***`tikzpicture` within `equation` environment gets a `font-latex-math-face`***

[image: tikzpicture within equation environment gets a font-latex-math-face]

Copy the following snippet to `*scratch*`, and do `M-x eval-buffer`.

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (defun my-LaTeX-mode-hook ()
            (hi-lock-mode 1)
            (highlight-regexp
             (rx (seq
                  "\\begin{tikzpicture}"
                  "[" (group (one-or-more any)) "]"
                  (group (minimal-match (one-or-more (or any "\n"))))
                  "\\end{tikzpicture}"))
             'hi-yellow 2)
            (font-lock-flush))
          t)
```

Visit the above `demo.tex` and do `M-x revert-buffer`.  This is how it looks

***`tikzpicture` gets its own face (which is `hi-yellow`)***

[image: tikzpicture gets its own face (which is hi-yellow)]

To highlight `tikzpicture` in `default` face, change `'hi-yellow` in the snippet to `'default`.

---

When I open the `.tex` file, and I do `C-h m` I get

The major mode is `LaTeX/P` mode defined in `tex-mode.el`:

This function has `:override` advice: `TeX-latex-mode`.

This is an `:override advice`, which means that `latex-mode` isn’t
run at all, and the documentation below may be irrelevant.

I also see

`TeX-latex-mode` is an autoloaded interactive byte-compiled Lisp
function in `latex.el`.

```
(TeX-latex-mode)
```

Major mode in AUCTeX for editing LaTeX files.
See info under AUCTeX for full documentation.

I had trouble finding the relevant `hook`.  You may have to find what `hook` is run in your case.  See https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/elpa.git/tree/latex.el?h=b91f15b3a375445985143ed1d6e41490ea62780a#n7161.  As the screenshots, there is no problem with the snippet.  May be our running environments are different.  May be try putting it on `TeX-mode-hook`.

To test the snippet, you don't have to have to put it on a `hook`.  Just add an `interactive` spec to `my-LaTeX-mode-hook`, and call the function with `M-x ...`.

(I am not a `tex` user, `auctex` is one of the big old packages which was outside of `Emacs` for a long time.  So, it has plenty of "hacks")

Comment: What is `TeX-latex-mode-hook-79i7rxb01mj` ? like where did `79i7rxb01mj0 ` come from?

Comment: When I try to add the function into configu file i am getting follwing error: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "‘TeX-latex-mode-hook-79i7rxb01mj0’ is not a valid ...")
  signal(error ("‘TeX-latex-mode-hook-79i7rxb01mj0’ is not a valid ..."))`

Comment: See the bottom of my previous answer.

Comment: Originally inside tikzpicuture `font-latex-sedate-face` is assigned for the `\node` (makes it bold and different color) to obtain this instead of `'default` do you have an idea what should be used?

Answer (score 1):

> https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30427/18414

The suggestion here is good enough.

By default, the `font-latex-verbatim-face` and  `font-latex-math-face` pick up the same color on `X`.

(With the same color assigned to `math` and `verbatim` environment, it is easy to mistake that the verbatim  environment is not working)

Similarly, in my earlier screenshot `sedate` face is left unconfigured.  Once you configure it, it is possible to distinguish between the `equation`, `tikzpicture` and `sedate` environments by carefull choosing the `face` properties.

(For example, in the config below, the `sedate` face has a `bold` property; even thought its `:foreground` property is overridden by `verbatim` face, the extra `bold` property makes it standout.)

Here is the screenshot

***`tikzpicture` in `math` environment***

[image: tikzpicture in math environment]

taken with

```lisp
(TeX-load-hack)

(custom-set-variables
 '(LaTeX-verbatim-environments
   '("verbatim" "verbatim*" "filecontents" "filecontents*" "tikzpicture")))

(custom-set-faces
 '(font-latex-sedate-face ((t (:foreground "DarkOrange" :weight bold))))
 '(font-latex-verbatim-face ((t (:inherit fixed-pitch :foreground "turquoise"))))
 '(my-tikzpicture-face ((t (:foreground "ForestGreen"))) t))
```

---

My earlier suggestion is superior to the `verbatim` environment because you can the `tikzpicture` can have its own color different from `verbatim` environments.

To get this

***`tikzpicture` gets its own face---that is `tikzpicture` is not using `verbatim` environment here***

[image: tikzpicture gets its own face]

do this

```lisp
(TeX-load-hack)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (defun TeX-latex-mode-hook-79i7rxb01mj0 ()
            (message "coming hree")
            (hi-lock-mode 1)
            (highlight-regexp
             (rx (seq
                  "\\begin{tikzpicture}"
                  (group (optional "[" (one-or-more any) "]"))
                  (group (minimal-match (zero-or-more (or any "\n"))))
                  "\\end{tikzpicture}"))
             'my-tikzpicture-face 2)
            (font-lock-flush))
          t)

(defface my-tikzpicture-face nil
  "Face for tikzpicture environment."
  :group 'font-latex-highlighting-faces)

(custom-set-faces
 '(font-latex-sedate-face ((t (:foreground "DarkOrange" :weight bold))))
 '(font-latex-verbatim-face ((t (:inherit fixed-pitch :foreground "turquoise"))))
 '(my-tikzpicture-face ((t (:foreground "ForestGreen"))) t))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### BUYER BEWARE!!!

***This is an experimental code ... Please don't use it in an `Emacs` session in which you are editing important documents like dissertation.  If there are bugs in the `font-lock` matcher, it will lock up your `Emacs`, and you need to essentially restart `Emacs`, and lose all the edits.***

##### A Bird's eye view of the snippet

What you want here is fontification of `tikzpicture` environment apart from its parent environment, `equation` in this case.

This scenario occurs in `org-mode`.  For example, the `src-blocks` are  fontified using their own environment, apart from the surrounding `org-mode` environment.

IOW, conceptually

- `tikzpicture` env => `#+begin_src ... #+end_src`
- `equation` env => `org-mode`

So, in the snippet below, the `tikzpicture` environment is copied over to temporary buffer in `latex-mode`, fontified there, and its  face properties transferred over to the original `tex` buffer.  This is exactly what the `org-mode` does while fontifying `src-blocks` natively.

IOW, the snippet is a verbatim copy of `org-mode` `src-block` fontification code, but to cater to the current requirements.

##### A Challenge: "Partial" or "Delayed" fontification is observed; but not addressed

`org-mode` and `auctex` aren't same, and their fontification  defaults are different ... So, for some reasons while using this code there will be partial fontification of `tikzpicture` blocks, which will go away as soon as you issue a command.

(My `font-lock`-fu is not good enough to address this "partial fontification" issue.)

That said, here is the real meat ...

To get this

***Fontify `tikzpicture` environment independently of its surrrounding `math` environment***

[image: Fontify tikzpicture environment independently of its surrrounding math environment]

(Its worth comparing the screenshot here with screenshots provided in earlier answers.  Note specifically the order of faces in `tikzpicture` environment)

do this

```lisp
(require 'tex-site)

(defface my-tikzpicture-face nil
  "Face for tikzpicture environment."
  :group 'font-latex-highlighting-faces)

(custom-set-faces
 '(font-latex-sedate-face ((t (:foreground "DarkOrange" :weight bold))))
 '(font-latex-verbatim-face ((t (:inherit fixed-pitch :foreground "turquoise"))))
 '(my-tikzpicture-face ((t (:foreground "ForestGreen"))) t))

(defvar-local suppress-my-tikzpicture-matcher nil)

(defun my-tikzpicture-matcher (limit)
  ;; (message "tikzpicture-matcher: %S" limit)
  (unless suppress-my-tikzpicture-matcher
    (let ((case-fold-search t))
      (while (re-search-forward
              (rx (seq
                   "\\begin{tikzpicture}"
                   (optional "[" (minimal-match (one-or-more any)) "]")
                   (group (minimal-match (zero-or-more (or any "\n"))))
                   "\\end{tikzpicture}"))
              limit t)
        (let ((start (match-beginning 0))
              (end (match-end 0))
              (lang 'latex-mode))
          (add-text-properties start end
                               '(font-lock-fontified t font-lock-multiline t))

          (let ((lang-mode 'latex-mode))
            (when (fboundp lang-mode)
              (let ((string (buffer-substring-no-properties start end))
                    (modified (buffer-modified-p))
                    (tex-buffer (current-buffer)))
                (remove-text-properties start end '(face nil))
                (font-lock-prepend-text-property start end 'face 'my-tikzpicture-face tex-buffer)
                (with-current-buffer
                    (get-buffer-create
                     (format " *tikzpicture fontification:%s [%s %s]*" lang-mode start end))
                  (setq suppress-my-tikzpicture-matcher t)
                  (let ((inhibit-modification-hooks nil))
                    (erase-buffer)
                    ;; Add string and a final space to ensure property change.
                    (insert string " "))
                  (unless (eq major-mode lang-mode) (funcall lang-mode))
                  (font-lock-ensure)
                  (let ((pos (point-min)) next)
                    (while (setq next (next-property-change pos))
                      ;; Handle additional properties from font-lock, so as to
                      ;; preserve, e.g., composition.
                      (dolist (prop (cons 'face font-lock-extra-managed-props))
                        (let ((new-prop (get-text-property pos prop)))
                          (font-lock-prepend-text-property
                           (+ start (1- pos)) (1- (+ start next)) prop new-prop
                           tex-buffer)
                          ;; (put-text-property
                          ;;  (+ start (1- pos)) (1- (+ start next)) prop new-prop
                          ;;  tex-buffer)
                          ))
                      (setq pos next))))
                (add-text-properties start end
                                     '(
                                       font-lock-fontified t
                                       fontified t
                                       font-lock-multiline t))

                (set-buffer-modified-p modified))))))
      (force-window-update (current-buffer))
      nil)))

;; (run-mode-hooks 'text-mode-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (defun my-LaTeX-mode-hook ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                                    (list '(my-tikzpicture-matcher))
                                    'append)
            (font-lock-flush)))
```

Comment: If you make `my-tikzpicture-face` inherit from `default` face, you will no longer notice that `tikzpicture` is within the `math` environment `(custom-set-faces '(my-tikzpicture-face ((t (:inherit default))) t))`.  This is ***experimental*** code---but most of it is derived from well-worn `org-mode` code---so use it  with some caution.

Comment: There are 3 answers of yours, which one should I use?

Comment: My recommendations from most reliable to the least:  **Use verbatim blocks (Solution 2)**.  it is the code which is already there in latex. **Uses `highlight-regexp` (Solution 1)**.  Amount of custom code is minimal.  **Use custom fontifier (Solution 3)**: Lots of custom code, and there are some delays in fontification.